# Monitor artifacts

Tags: memory, motherboard

Some days ago, the problem started as pc shutting down randomly
Then after some days it became as shown in the image the pc freezes sometimes with noise if something is playing on speaker and the monitor will be as shown in the image monitor artifact's.

[image]

Now the pc shuts down and restart frequency increased. It turns on and after some seconds turns and happens again.

Comment: Look for messages in the Event Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

OK some weeks before I asked this question, I had added a 4gb ram stick to my pc. The issue was solved when I took out this ram stick out of my pc. Now the problem is solved.
I am curious as to how my ram did this does anyone know why.